# list all Joinpoints in Spring's Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

Is it somehow possible to list all Joinpoints that are matching a given Pointcut in Spring's Aspect Oriented Programming.
I guess spring has some kind of registry where all Joinpoints are in at runtime.

e.g. for

```
@Pointcut("execution(* transfer(..))")
```

there should be a list somewhere, containing all methods that are called "transfer"

Comment: scan for annotations using ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html

Comment: can you give an example on how to do it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how Spring exactly handles AOP internally, but I do know it creates dynamic proxies (JDK or CGLIB types) during runtime. So there might not be a complete list unless all target classes/interfaces are already loaded when you generate your report.

But I have an elegant workaround for you: Just for the purpose of generating the report, compile your aspects with pure AspectJ (AspectJ syntax is basically a superset of Spring AOP), using this option for the AspectJ compiler *ajc*:

```
-showWeaveInfo      display information about weaving
```

It will list all woven joinpoints. For statically determined joinpoints like `execution()` this is ideal. Dynamic joinpoints like `cflow()`, `cflowbelow()` (both are not supported by Spring AOP anyway) and `if()` can only be evaluated during runtime, in those cases more joinpoints will be woven than might actually be used later during runtime, just to be on the safe side and not miss any possible joinpoints.

Besides, in Eclipse using AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) you have nice cross-reference views in which you can list and dynamically navigate from pointcuts to affected joinpoints and vice versa.

Just give it a spin, good luck! But maybe someone knows a pure Spring solution for you. I do not because I never used Spring.

P.S.: Here is a little example in pure AspectJ:

**Java classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public int transfer() { return 11; }
    public void transfer(int number) { }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Whatever {
    public String transfer(int number) { return "foo"; }
    public void transfer(String text) { }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class TransferInterceptor {
    @Before("execution(* transfer(..))")
    public void intercept(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Compiler output with `-showWeaveInfo`:**

```
Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.String de.scrum_master.app.Whatever.transfer(int))' in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Whatever' (Whatever.java:4) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.TransferInterceptor' (TransferInterceptor.aj:10)
Join point 'method-execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Whatever.transfer(java.lang.String))' in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Whatever' (Whatever.java:5) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.TransferInterceptor' (TransferInterceptor.aj:10)
Join point 'method-execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.transfer())' in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Application' (Application.java:4) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.TransferInterceptor' (TransferInterceptor.aj:10)
Join point 'method-execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.transfer(int))' in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Application' (Application.java:5) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.TransferInterceptor' (TransferInterceptor.aj:10)
```